# Plotting a contour graph in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I am new to Windows programming.
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. It's a Visual C++ Win32 project.
I am working on a program to visualize data from a measurement. The data have  X, Y, and Z points.

I would like to plot these data in a contour plot. The Z coordinate gives me the "height" information; X and Y the position of the height.

The amount of data for X and Y are about 30 measurement points (for each). That makes about 900 measurement points for Z.

I have already installed the Boost C++ library, but I don't know how to use it for my purposes. Furthermore i read something about a library called `chplot.h`, which should include a plot function. Would that work for me, and if so, where can I download it?

Are there any possibilities for plotting a "countour plot" or a surface plot or something similar in C++?

Comment: http://qwt.sourceforge.net/

Comment: [root.cern.ch](http://root.cern.ch)